# Django/DRF/JWT doesn't go to the DB when authenticating token, but request.user has all the details?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

How is it possible that

1. JWT does not go through the database to authenticate a user
2. `request.user` is a fully featured object with all the fields already populated.

Which one is true?

1. The database *is* used
2. Every field of `User` is encoded onto the token and decoded at request time to be made available.

Comment: Second is true.

Comment: Although jwt verifies credentials before giving a jwt token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of the second option is true.

JWT generates a token based on, for example `user` and `password`. When received from a client, the server decodes it, and validates the information received.

Here's a nice graph:

[image]

If you go to the debugger in https://jwt.io/ you'll see the composition of a token. HEADER - PAYLOAD - VERIFY SIGNATURE. And if you need an in depth explanation, you can start [here](https://jwt.io/introduction/)

In the case of DRF-JWT you can see how the payload of the jwt token is made in [here](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/master/rest_framework_jwt/utils.py#L42).

Comment: so that's strange. if the payload isn't returning ALL fields from User and no database is ever called, how come I can see my `request.user.first_name` value when I start processing the API call?

Comment: The payload includes the `user.pk`. DRF & DRF-JWT process the token, get the pk, request the user, and inject it in the `request` object, making it available for you.

Comment: (I am only talking about case #4 in your chart - this is the request I am making). So I can see valid value under `request.user.first_name` because I accessed `request.user.first_name` which made Django's ORM go ahead and hit the DB for it? If I only needed the `user.pk` to process the request, the DB would not be hit as the `user.pk` is already there from the token decrypted, right? The DB would be hit only if I access `request.user.<field_not_in_the_token>`. Is that an accurate assumption?

Comment: No, DRF JWT will always hit the db to retrieve the user, check https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/master/rest_framework_jwt/authentication.py#L59
Basically, once the server receives the token, if valid, retrieves the user from the db, so, the db is hit. One you make `request.user.first_name` the user has already been retrieved from the db. The cost is minimal, you shouldn't be worried about it. Is there any reason why you need to know if the db was hit?

Comment: The difference with traditional token systems is that with jwt you don't need to store the token in your db. Any authentication for django will get the user from the db, unless there is an option to prevent so, which I don't know, you should read every setting from drf-jwt for example.

Comment: That makes the value of the whole thing questionable. I'd rather store the token in my DB, so that I can revoke it when I need to, rather than having non-revokable tokens that must be time limited and the user bothered with renewing them with username/password once they completely expire.

Comment: Come on, JWT is a huge standard, it has solutions to most of the cases you present. Is possible to blacklist tokens, to create new tokens before a previous one expires, because you are reading the content of the token, so you don't care if there is more than one for the same user. Also, you avoid using the DB which has the benefit of less I/O, less size (or having to remove old tokens), avoiding errors like duplicates. But it might be possible that it doesn't fit your use case, so you might pick another one. So far I've been really happy with the JWT solution to authetication. Cheers!

Comment: I guess you're right. Thanks for the detailed explanation.